# Error: [$resource:badcfg] , how can I fix that?

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm just getting my first steps with angular and stuff, here's my service:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('timeTracker')
        .factory('time', time);

        function time($resource) {

            // ngResource call to our static data
            var Time = $resource('data/time.json');

            function getTime() {
                // $promise.then allows us to intercept the results
                // which we will use later
                return Time.query().$promise.then(function(results) {
                    return results;
                }, function(error) { // Check for errors
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }

            return {
                getTime: getTime,
            }
        }
```

The 'data/time.json' is pre-filled, I don't have a back-end system yet.
And here's my controller:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('timeTracker')
        .controller('TimeEntry', TimeEntry);

        function TimeEntry(time) {

            // vm is our capture variable
            var vm = this;

            vm.timeentries = [];

            // Fetches the time entries from the static JSON file
            // and puts the results on the vm.timeentries array
            time.getTime().then(function(results) {
                vm.timeentries = results;
                console.log(vm.timeentries);
            }, function(error) { // Check for errors
                console.log(error);
            });

        }
})();
```

So far I've just tried to wire all together in a index.html file, but something keeps going wrong.
My index's body looks like this:

```
<body ng-app="timeTracker" ng-controller="TimeEntry as vm">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Time Tracker</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid time-entry">
            <div class="timepicker">
                <span class="timepicker-title label label-primary">Clock In</span>
                <timepicker ng-model="vm.clockIn" hour-step="1" minute-step="1" show-meridian="true">
                </timepicker> 
            </div>
            <div class="timepicker">
                <span class="timepicker-title label label-primary">Clock Out</span>
                <timepicker ng-model="vm.clockOut" hour-step="1" minute-step="1" show-meridian="true">
                </timepicker>
            </div>
            <div class="time-entry-comment">                
                <form class="navbar-form">
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="vm.comment" placeholder="Enter a comment">
                    </input>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.logNewTime()">Log Time</button>
                </form>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="well timeentry" ng-repeat="time in vm.timeentries">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> 
                        {{time.user_firstname}} {{time.user_lastname}}</h4>
                        <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> {{time.comment}}</p>                  
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 time-numbers">
                        <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> 
                        {{time.end_time | date:'mediumDate'}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Anyway, I couldn't figure out a way to make this work so far. I keep getting the same error in the console log :

```
[Error] Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object
http://localhost/TimeTracker/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:32
http://localhost/TimeTracker/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:587:40
processQueue@http://localhost/TimeTracker/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13248:29
http://localhost/TimeTracker/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13264:39
$eval@http://localhost/TimeTracker/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14466:28
$digest@http://localhost/TimeTracker/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14282:36
$apply@http://localhost/TimeTracker/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14571:31
done@http://localhost/TimeTracker/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9698:53
completeRequest@http://localhost/TimeTracker/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9888:15
requestLoaded@http://localhost/TimeTracker/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9829:24
    (anonymous function) (angular.js, line 11655)
    (anonymous function) (angular.js, line 8596)
    processQueue (angular.js, line 13256)
    (anonymous function) (angular.js, line 13264)
    $eval (angular.js, line 14466)
    $digest (angular.js, line 14282)
    $apply (angular.js, line 14571)
    done (angular.js, line 9698)
    completeRequest (angular.js, line 9888)
    requestLoaded (angular.js, line 9829)
```

So, splitting out the index's body, everything works just fine within the `<nav>` tag, but not a single dot comes out from the `"container"`.

Comment: `Time.query()` expects an array. Are you using an object?

Comment: I don't think so actually. Eventually, in the controller, I fetch all the entries from the JSON file into timeentries[] array.

Comment: What's inside of `data/time.json`?

Comment: `/* data/time.json */
    
[
    {
      "id":1,
      "user_id":1,
      "user_firstname":"First name",
      "user_lastname":"Last name",
      "start_time":"2015-05-23T09:55:32Z",
      "end_time":"2015-05-23T12:07:09Z",
      "comment": "Front-end setup."
    }
]`  
This is a sample of what it contains. Basically `n` copy of the above element.

Comment: I made a live example of your code. Apparently it is working ok.
http://embed.plnkr.co/RSIBLVHB8HZ03xPAa0nZ

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you forgot a few lines

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('timeTracker')
        .factory('time', time);

        function time($resource) {

            // ngResource call to our static data
            var Time = $resource('data/time.json');

            function getTime() {
                // $promise.then allows us to intercept the results
                // which we will use later
                return Time.query().$promise.then(function(results) {
                    return results;
                }, function(error) { // Check for errors
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }

            return {
                getTime: getTime,
            }
        }
```

Is missing the lines below:

```
})();
```

Working code:
http://embed.plnkr.co/RSIBLVHB8HZ03xPAa0nZ

Answer (score 0):

'use strict'; doesn't allow implicit dependency declaration. Try

```
angular
        .module('timeTracker')
        .factory('time', ['$rosource', time]);
```

and

```
angular
    .module('timeTracker')
    .controller('TimeEntry', ['time', TimeEntry]);
```

or remove the 'use strict';

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't fix my problem. Console keep showing same error.